# Minimum spanning tree and shortest path

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, minimum-spanning-tree

I was given a problem that said:

given a connected directed graph with integer weights (both positive and negative),
develop an algorithm that finds the shortest path between two vertices.

I thought I could use a minimum spanning tree algorithm such as kruskal's and then use
maybe dijkstra's algorithm to show that since in an MST, every vertex only has one incomming edge, dijkstra's algorithm will work even with negative weights.

does this sound copasteic?

p.s. I'm having trouble proving that an MST contains the shortest path for a directed graph,
for every vertex.

Comment: Consider an n-dimensional grid for n >= 2. A MST, like any tree, has leaves with only one edge connected to them. A point on an n-dimensional grid has n adjacent points in n different directions, so the MST does not support all possible shortest paths to adjacent points.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should note that your graph should not have any negative cycle.

Second, Normally Dikstra would not work with graphs with negative weights.

Thirst, [Bellman-Ford Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) could be used for finding shortest path in a directed with-negative-weights graph.

Comment: One of the stipulations for a minimum spanning tree has no cylces. Kruskal's algorithm proves that. But thanks for the link

Comment: You can use Bellman-ford algorithm, without creating MST. I guess that would be faster solution

Comment: @ReCoNciLiaTiOn you are confusing the initial graph, that could also have negative cycles, and the spanning tree that you want to produce, that is a tree and hence has no cycles.

Comment: I think you **should** use Bellman-ford without creating an MST first.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having trouble proving that an MST contains the shortest path for a directed graph, for every vertex.

That's because it's false. Take a triangle graph with edge weights 2, 3, and 4. The MST contains only the edges of weight 2 and 3, but the shortest path has weight 4 and the path through the MST has weight 5.

Given this, embedding minimal spanning trees in your algorithm seems like a bad idea.